# conditionall if == on javascript

Tags: javascript

After clicking on the image is big, so how back to being small when clicked again? Is something wrong in the code? the conditional == or the syntax?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function () {


        var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
        thumbnailElement.className;
        thumbnailElement.className = "";

        if (thumbnailElement.className == "") {
            thumbnailElement.className = "small"

        } else if (thumbnailElement.className = "") {
            thumbnailElement.className = "small"
        } else {
            thumbnailElement.className = ""
```

Comment: You might want to think about changing to [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). The interface is cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code for a [mcve]? Your current snippet looks like it is cut off in the end. Also it's unclear what the class `small` is doing, and how you'd get a "big image after clicking".

Comment: `=` is assignment, not a comparison like you'd expect in a conditional.

Comment: You *always* assign the value `""` just before checking whether the value equals `""`. That doesn't make sense, it will always enter the first `if` block and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

else if (thumbnailElement.className = "")

Note the single ='s, this should be ===

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

You are also performing the same comparison twice in the first if and if else.

```
 if (thumbnailElement.className == "") {
     thumbnailElement.className = "small"

 }  else if (thumbnailElement.className = "") { <-- this is the same as the first one, but it's the wrong syntax
     thumbnailElement.className = "small"
 }
```

There are also other small issues in your syntax which aren't going to work.

```
var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById ("smart_thumbnail");
     thumbnailElement.className; <--- this isnt doing anything
     thumbnailElement.className = ""; <--- every time you run the function you automatically remove the class
```

Try this:

```
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
      if(thumbnailElement.classList.contains("big"){
         thumbnailElement.classList.remove("big")
         thumbnailElement.classList.add("small")
      }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xb4azyn/ I've created a fiddle with a working example